# Run method in start up (Net 7)

Tags: asp.net-core

Which is the best practise for running a method in project start up?

In meantime i have create a class and a static method in it.

```
public class SqlServices
{
    public static void Init()
    {
       //Run SqlServices
    }
}
```

And then i just run my static method before application start inside Program.cs.

```
using WebApplication3;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

SqlServices.Init();

app.Run();
```

Is this a good practise or there is a better way? Thank you.

Comment: Better according to what criteria, to do what? What does `Init` do? All the code in `Program.cs` runs at startup, in a compiler-generated static method. You could extract the initialization code into a local method if you wanted. If there code is just a couple of lines, that could be enough. If not, it's a good idea to extract it to another file, just to clean things up. If you want to use configuration settings or services, it's not enough. If you want different initialization for different database products, you probably need classes that implement a common interface

Comment: If you are dealing with database connections it is usually a good idea to utilize IoC/DI in your application. If you are familiar with [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection), take a look at [Hosted Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services)

Comment: Could you please provide me an example?

Comment: An example for what? What are you trying to do? You don't need a Hosted service to run anything on startup, in fact it's *not* a good idea. Your application will start working before that service had a chance to finish

Comment: That is not correct. The start method of hosted services block the startup process. "StartAsync should be limited to short running tasks because hosted services are run sequentially, and no further services are started until StartAsync runs to completion." This approach is utilized by many frameworks as well, like ABP.

Comment: This question already has two close votes because it's unclear what you want. It's impossible to say whether one way of doing something is better than another when we don't know what that something is. Creating databases and tables requires access a connection string which `SqlServices.Init();` doesn't have.

Comment: @benyogyerek ABP uses a ton of bad practices. The very snippet you posted shows how bad this one is. What's the point of blocking another thread when you can just call a static method anyway? A hosted service is meant for long running jobs, not one-offs. It's not needed for a one-off. If you want to use DI, `app.Services.GetRequiredService<MyConfiguredClass>()` is enough

Comment: @benyogyerek besides, everything before `app.Run` is part of the application startup. Hosted services aren't created until `app.Run` is called, when the host is already active (that includes DI, logging, configuration) and the middleware registered and ready to run.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, if you are in a static context, you can call simply call a static method, OP started with having created a static class. I suggested an IoC based approach and provided an example demonstrating the idea, when asked.

Comment: That's not what you posted at all, you added code that delays initialization while blocking long-running services. You don't need a hosted service to use IoC. That's done with `app.Services.GetRequiredService`. Besides, *why* use IoC at all? What makes this a better choice than a local or static method? You can't say if you don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
public class DbInitializerHostedService : IHostedService
{
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // The code in here will run when the application starts, and block the startup process until finished
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // The code in here will run when the application stops
        // In your case, nothing to do
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Program.cs`:

```cs
// ...

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddHostedService<DbInitializerHostedService>();

// ...
```

You can use the Dependency Injection container to inject services to this class and further isolate parts of your logic and consume them (for example sharing the connection string or SQL connection between this service and the app itself). Check the documentation I linked above in the comments for examples using an `ILogger` for the hosted service.

Comment: This is a bad idea. This will *delay* the execution of the initialization code until *after* the application starts